# Correlation between binary variables

Tags: correlation, p-value, chi-squared-test, binary-data, pearson-r

Long story short - I am lost among the ways to check for relation (whether there is any) between binary variables.

**Context** - I am working on a side project where I try to analyze marketplace data and see which variables are related to items being sold (the goal is to find out what can be done to sell more items). So I am trying to analyze data and basically see which variables are correlated to the dependent variable which is "sold" (True/False). I am having some difficulties with binary data. For e.g. there's an independent variable "sale" (True/False) and I want to know whether putting an item on sale increases the probability of selling it.

My first instinct was to use the chi-squared test for it:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

contigency = pd.crosstab(df.sold, df.sale)
c, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(contingency)
```

I got **p = 2.5e-142**. At this point, it seemed right to make a conclusion that sale definitely (since the p-value is very small) has an impact on whether an item was sold or not.

But the I started reading more and found this - https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/8756479308317006?fbclid=IwAR2OEdL0WwghG8gyCp-ee3zYhgVhAhJVGynTBWVUw3JeJfgaWhytMylPbrY. Here it says that

> One common way of measuring association
> in such a table is to use the phi coefficient, ϕ.
> Values of ϕ lie between 0 and 1.

And according to Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient), if I understood it correctly, for binary variables **Matthews correlation coefficient** should be used. But MCC shows that there's no dependence between sold and sale:

```
from sklearn import metrics
mc = metrics.matthews_corrcoef(df[b], df.sold_in_30_days)
```

returns **mc=0.03**.

Also same as for MCC happened with Pearson's correlation coefficient - i got it to be same as MCC (0.03).

**My thoughts** - both MCC and Pearson's measure correlation which makes the most sense for numerical values and measure liner dependency, therefore it does not make sense to measure it for binary.

**Question** - So for the cases where we need to know whether one binary variable impacts the other the ultimate measure is the p-value of the chi-squared test?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How would you do it for continuous variables?

Comment: Thanks! So for the continuous vs continuous, I'd first inspect it graphically (using scatterplot) and then use either Pearson correlation or maybe something like this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/393903/quadratic-polynomial-how-to-test-correlation-between-x-and-y if graphically it would look like e.g. quadratic.
And for continuous vs binary I am actually not sure.

Comment: You can [visualize](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56322/237901) the relationship between two categorical variables as well, though admittedly two binary  variables don't make for a gripping plot. And some [ideas](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/428445/237901) for plotting a continuous variable against a categorical one.

Comment: Matthews correlation, Phi coefficient and Pearson correlation on binary variables are all the same thing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient

Comment: hi @cinnamon at the end what did you end up using to see the correlation b/w 2 binary variables?